# Associate a vertical list with daily hours to a weekly list index in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a horizontal list like in the following video:

https://youtu.be/-n7MDD8Px8c

This list is a weekly index generated by this code:

```
  Expanded(
    child: PageView.builder(
      controller: _pageController,
      itemBuilder: (context, weekIndex) {
        return ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: WeekDays.days.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            DateTime now = DateTime.now();
            int milliseconds = now.millisecondsSinceEpoch -
                (now.weekday - 1) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 +
                weekIndex * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 +
                index * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            DateTime dayDateTime =
                DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(milliseconds);
            int monthIndex = dayDateTime.month - 1;
            List months = [
              'Gen',
              'Feb',
              'Mar',
              'Apr',
              'Mag',
              'Giu',
              'Lug',
              'Ago',
              'Set',
              'Ott',
              'Nov',
              'Dic'
            ];
            List weekdays = ['Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Gio', 'Ven', 'Sab', 'Dom'];
            String month = months[monthIndex];
            String day = dayDateTime.day.toString();
            String weekday = weekdays[dayDateTime.weekday - 1];
            String date = weekday + ' ' + day + ' ' + month;
            return Container(
              width: 100,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Card(
                    color: now.weekday == index + 1 && weekIndex == 0
                        ? Colors.orange[900]
                        : Colors.orange,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 40,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          date,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13, color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    ),
  )
```

Below each element of the list, I need to build a scrollable list of hours of the day where the user can tap to make a reservation of specific hours for a specific day.

How I can get an independent list below each weekly element list?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the logic of your app, but from a quick look I would see the issue with `toggleHoursIndex(hoursIndex);`

You need to distinguish between the hours of the different days. You can use for example variables of the kind `reserved[day][timeslot]` or I guess in your case `toggleHoursIndex(dayIndex, hoursIndex);`

UPDATE 2: in pseudo code, I would do something like this

```dart
class AState extends State<A> {
List<List<bool>> timeSlot;

  ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: WeekDays.days.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int indexH) {
          return ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertictal,
            itemCount: WeekDays.days.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int indexV) {
            return indexV == 0 ? 
                    datecell(indexH, month) :
                    timecell(indexH,indexV-1)
            }
          );
        }
      )
      
   Widget datecell (int day, int month) {
    return Text("$day $month");
      }
   Widget timecell (int day, int slotposition) {
   final List<String> time = ["08:00 - 08:20", ...] ;
    return FlatButton(
      child: Text(time[slotposition]),
      onPressed: setState(() => timeSlot[day][slotposition] = true;
      }
}
```

Hope this now better understandable

Comment: as you can see the code for Hours is into a child of the weekly list, I think this is the issue, because if I take the code of the Hours and I put into another class it works without select the full horizontal list.
But I need to keep it into the main code and associate the vertical list of each day

Comment: it is not so easy to see. It is always good practice to remove not necessary code and to highlight critical areas with comments for people answering, here. On 2nd view now, do you create the time table with rows of the same time? I would create columns per day and each day has a week day on top and the different time slots underneath. And this column I would place in a row with all the displayed weekdays. But however you do this, your issue needs to be rectified by clearly combining day and time for the processing

Comment: Considering the first part of code where I just have the horizontal List with the weeks I think this is correct.
Thus, How to add one column of List below each element of the horizontal scrolling list?

Comment: datacell and timecell what do you mean?

Comment: what I am basically saying, nest the vertical list into the horizontal list. Then show the widget (eg card) with the date as the first element (datecell), and the widgets with the time as the 2nd to nth. I'll edit the answer in a minute to make it more understandable